# Attributes in locale file not registering in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, locale

I am making a Rails app to replicate my currently-online arcade website that I wrote in PHP. The only controller I have right now is 'games' and I have some fields such as title and description. When I submit the form and I don't meet the requirements of the validators I have set in my models/game.rb, it will show a red bar underneath containing the error, such as " is too short (minimum is 20 characters)." For some reason, it doesn't put the field name in front of the word 'is'.

Yes, it is obvious when you look at it that it is referring to the field above, but there is definitely something wrong here. I have created other Rails apps in the past with the same issue and there actually hasn't been a time in the past few months that I've been playing with Rails that I've seen this working right.

Screenshot here: http://postimg.org/image/v3kt6xia1/

Below is my code.

models/game.rb

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  $msg_success_icon = "fa fa-check fa-lg"
  $game_categories = ["Adventure", "Arcade", "Action", "Racing", "Puzzle", "Strategy", "Sports", "Shooting", "Misc", "Movies"]

  validates :title, {
    :presence => true,
    :length => {
      :minimum => 2
    }
  }

  validates :description, {
    :presence => true,
    :length => {
      :minimum => 20
    }
  }
end
```

config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      game:
        one: Game
        other: Games
    attributes:
      game:
        title: 'Title'
        description: 'Description'
        game_width: 'Width'
        game_height: 'Height'
        category: ''
    errors:
      models:
        game:
          attributes:
            title:
              blank: 'okay fill that title field in!'
            embed_url:
              blank: 'must link to the game file (.swf & .dcr extensions allowed)'
            thumb_url:
              blank: 'must link to a image of the game (.jpg, .gif, & .png allowed)'
            category:
              inclusion: ''
      messages:
        too_short:
          one: must be at least 1 character long.
          other: must be at least %{count} characters long.
        not_a_number: must be a number.
```

I compared this code to several examples that I found online and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I feel like the problem lies elsewhere but I don't know where. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `$msg_success_icon` in Ruby means "global variable", which means that variable will be available EVERYWHERE in your code. Perhaps you meant to define a constant instead, such as `MSG_SUCCESS_ICON`?

Comment: On second thought, that looks to me like view logic. Why is it even in the model in the first place?

Comment: I meant to remove those variables from my post, my apologies. I put that there as a global variable on purpose. I wasn't aware that it was bad practice to place those in the model. Thank you for this.